# JPA Named Query | Delete | Update/delete queries cannot be typed :

Tags: jpa, named-query

My Code is below:
Entity

```
@Entity(name = "TerpCrtV")
@NamedQueries({
     @NamedQuery(name = "deleteAllCrt", query = "DELETE FROM TerpCrtV")
})
```

Named query is called as below in DAO Layer:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="masterPU")
private EntityManager entityManagerMaster;

public int deleteAllCustomerTeams() throws Exception {
    return entityManagerMaster.createNamedQuery("deleteAllCrt", TerpCrtV.class).executeUpdate();
}
```

It is called as below using usertransaction:
User Transaction is EJB one and injected in the bean

```
private void persist(List<TerpCrtV> terpCustomerTeams) throws Exception  {
    logger.info("In CustomerTeamsCopierImpl: Delete all CRT");
    userTransaction.begin();
    deleteAllCrtV();
    userTransaction.commit();
```

Error i am facing is here under:

```
2021-04-05 12:36:53,454 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (EJB default - 2) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component MasterdataPersistence for method public int com.evry.integrator.crm.persistence.MasterdataPersistence.deleteAllCustomerTeams() throws java.lang.Exception: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Update/delete queries cannot be typed
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:203)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:364)
       ]com.evry.integrator.crm.persistence.MasterdataPersistence$$$view7.deleteAllCustomerTeams(Unknown Source)
        at com.evry.integrator.terpcrm.schedular.CustomerTeamsCopierImpl.deleteAllCrtV(CustomerTeamsCopierImpl.java:86)
        at com.evry.integrator.terpcrm.schedular.CustomerTeamsCopierImpl.persist(CustomerTeamsCopierImpl.java:64)
        at com.evry.integrator.terpcrm.schedular.CustomerTeamsCopierImpl.importDataFromTerpAndInsertToMasterdata(CustomerTeamsCopierImpl.java:139)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that you cannot have the second paramter when calling `createNamedQuery` (because you are not returning any result).

This should work:

```
entityManagerMaster.createNamedQuery("deleteAllCrt").executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it weird since the method is deprecated, but you need to remove the second parameter which is the class instance TerpCrtV.class